# Execute before_filter every 5min , in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple (3) before_filter functions in Application_controller.

They look similar to  this:

```
def give_vip_recomend

  @list = List.where("billing_id =?", 5).first

  if @list.present?

  @v = Girl.where("country_id=?",@list.country_id).where("vip_recomend >= ?", Time.now).count
  @b = Girl.where("country_id=?",@list.country_id).where("recomend >= ?", Time.now).count

  @count = @v+@b

    if @count < 8  #pārbauda recomended anketas jau ir 4                   
      @advertisement = Girl.find_by_id(@list.advertisement_id)
      @advertisement.vip_highlight = Time.now + 2.days 
      @advertisement.paid = true    
      @advertisement.save
      @list.delete
      flash[:notice] = "Izdevās piešķirt  vip_highlight - gaidīšanas sarakstā esošam"
    end
  end
end
```

At this point I can't see performance issues, but later I believe it will cause some headaches.

**Question:**

Is it possible to execute those before_filters one by one. For example:

```
every 5 minutes - execute "X" before_filter
every 7 minutes - execute "Y" before_filter
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that should be considered a part of your controllers' jobs.

Consider looking at the [`whenever` gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and processing jobs like this via cron.